# Need help finding socket size on 2017 Chevy Cruze 1.4L oil filter

Tags: chevrolet, oil, oil-filter, cruze

Hoping someone on here can help me more than google. I don’t know if I just have no clue where to look but I can’t find this info for the life of me.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If you put your title in google the first link has the answer..

Comment: ironically enough they are also complaining in that post to google it...........

Comment: Sockets pop up on google, yes. 32mm, 36mm, and 28mm mostly. That doesn’t give me an answer lmao.

Comment: ***2nd gen is an under the car canister type filter****

Comment: You could buy the oil filter and take it with you as you look for a socket.

Answer (score 1):

[According to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7vsusVU4Jk) it is just a regular spin on oil filter, no special socket required. About one minute into the video shows it.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have that gen Cruze. I need help finding the one for the ‘17 (2nd gen models)

Comment: Changed my answer above.